# Naive forecast day-ahead

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I want to do a naive forecast with a dataset I have and I am struggling a bit doing so.

```
    values = DataFrame(dataset.iloc[:, -1])
    Y_naive = pd.concat([values.shift(24), values], axis=1)
    Y_naive.columns = ['t', 't+1']
    x = Y_naive.values
```

What I basically have is hourly data where I want to compare the last column regarding its manifestation {0,1}. Since I want to compare this naive forecast with other day-ahead predictors I want to use the data of one day before (shift(24)) to predict the actual manifestation. 
Naive forecast:

```
    def naive_forecast(x):
        return x
    predictions = list()
    for x in test_x:
        yhat = naive_forecast(x)
        predictions.append(yhat)
```

For me it is very unclear how to do the mapping process. That means how to give over the argument that for binary classification testing I want to use the data from 24 hours before to map it on the data now for the entire dataset iteratively. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forecasting#Na.C3.AFve_approach)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is going to be very hard to answer without a clearer picture of what your original dataframe looks like. What are the columns and rows of values?

I'll take a stab at answering your question as best I can. A naive forecast is just the value of the previous period. Assuming your original dataframe is set up like

```python
    index   'original'
    time1     x1
    time2     x2
    time3     x3
```

Naive prediction column will just be the values in original shifted to the appropriate time indices. With a simple example of df as

```python
    index                            'original'
    2017-08-19 17:49:08.102868         0
    2017-08-20 17:49:08.109869         1
    2017-08-21 17:49:08.109869         2
    2017-08-22 17:49:08.109869         3
```

Shifting by one day:

```python
    naive_prediction = df.shift(1, freq=datetime.timedelta(days=1))
    naive_prediction.columns = ['naive_prediction']
```

Returns

```python
    index                       'naive_prediction'
    2017-08-20 17:49:08.102868         0
    2017-08-21 17:49:08.109869         1
    2017-08-22 17:49:08.109869         2
    2017-08-23 17:49:08.109869         3
```

Now we just need to [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) these two dataframes, and the naive_prediction column will contain the appropriate values for each index position.

```python
    final_df = df.merge(naive_prediction, how="outer", left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Which should return a final_df of

```python
    index                          'original'   'naive_prediction'
    2017-08-19 17:49:08.102868         0           NaN
    2017-08-20 17:49:08.109869         1            0
    2017-08-21 17:49:08.109869         2            1
    2017-08-22 17:49:08.109869         3            2
    2017-08-23 17:49:08.109869        NaN           3
```

where the value of each index position is equal to the original value of the previous index position.